# Why are static type errors in this example code only reported at run-time by Rascal?

Tags: rascal

According to the [Rascal documentation](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Concepts/StaticTyping/StaticTyping.html), the language is statically typed. However the type errors are only reported on runtime.

For example, when I create this module, I expect a type error because I am assigning a real to an int variable:

```
module Example

void example() {
  int x = 1.0;
  println(x);
}
```

When I import the module on the REPL, and finally run the function:

```
rascal>import Example;
ok
rascal>example()
|project://Test/src/Example.rsc|(39,7,<4,6>,<4,13>): Expected int, but got real
☞ Advice
```

Comment: Such rascals, they didn't even provide a type checker?

Comment: FYI: I'm a developer on the Rascal team, and we are moving our community to stackoverflow. (before ask.rascal-mpl.org). We are seeding some of our knowledge. If you downvote, could someone please explain what rule we violated? (also see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

Comment: I did not downvote you, but I think u were downvoted  because its not a programming related question.

Comment: so, is this one answered Davy? or do you think we should improve?

Comment: I marked yours as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is running ahead of the plan for Rascal. Rascal has a type system that can be statically checked, but the type checker is not integrated yet.

Currently the interpreter is checking types at run-time. Note that the error messages that it reports contain only "static types". The interpreter is doing both abstract interpretation and concrete interpretation (running) the code at the same time. This allowed us to rapidly evolve the language because the code for the interpretation and the type checking for each construct is woven closely together.

When we introduce the type checking stage, we hope to use the types and the resolved names to get some more speed out of the interpreter, and simplify the interpreter's code again, and of course get the errors to the programmer sooner.

Comment: Update: an experimental compiler for Rascal is nearly finished. Working on the compiler requires finishing the type checker...

Answer (score 1):

Rascal does have a static type checker, which is written in Rascal itself. It covers most of the language (the only, currently, unsupported feature is keyword parameters). To use it, right click on a Rascal file opened in Eclipse (using the Rascal plugin), select "Experimental", then "Run static checker". As the menu name implies, this is experimental, so please let us know if you find problems.