# In a visit expression, can the default be labeled like the cases?

Tags: rascal

Example:

```
visit(Sometree)
{
    case a:someNodeA(_,_): HandleNodeA(a);
    default:               Handle(???);
}
```

So i want to handle all the other cases by using `default`, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

visit does not support default because it needs something specific to bind while visiting. Instead you can write a pattern that matches truly everything. For example:

```
visit(sometree) {
   case node x : handleAllTreeLikeThings(x);
   case str y(value x, value y) : handleAllBinaryTrees(y, x, y);
   case value x : handleAllValuesWhatsoever(x);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Although using default in a visit, like in my example, does compile and run! With unexpected behaviour(for me atleast).

Comment: That missing complaint is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164843/why-are-static-type-errors-in-this-example-code-only-reported-at-run-time-by-ras/16165202#16165202